# Complete atomic boolean algebras as coalgebras of some endofunctor on Set

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, boolean-algebra, coalgebras

I was hoping to use the fact that CABAs are powersets with extra structure on the morphisms to find an endofunctor $F:\text{Set}\to\text{Set}$ with $\text{Set}^{op}\simeq\text{Coalg}F$. I started by seeing that $\text{Coalg}\bar{2}\simeq ( \text{Set}/2)$, where $2$ is the cardinal of the same cardinality, and $\bar{2}$ is the constant functor on said cardinal. Coalgebras on this are just atomic lattices with the usual order-preserving morphisms, right? So we should just be able to build up on $\bar{2}$ to accommodate the extra requirements on these coalgebras that turn them into complete atomic boolean algebras. This is where I am stuck. Unfortunately Google hasn't helped me much, and the nLab page doesn't mention coalgebras of endofunctors.

Also, references on where I can read more about working with algebras and coalgebras of endofunctors are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Complete atomic boolean algebras are _algebras_ for a _monad_. What makes you think they should be _coalgebras_ for an _endofunctor_?

Comment: I am aware of that, but I was curious about the existence of an endofunctor that they would be coalgebras of. I am not very knowledgeable on these things: does being an algebra for a monad mean not being a coalgebra for some endofunctor, if the base category has enough structure?

Comment: There are ways to prove such results, yes. For instance, the category of coalgebras for an endofunctor will be closed under retracts in a strong sense.

Comment: Okay, interesting. Thank you.